# How to switch between Debug.WriteLine() at debug and Console.WriteLine() in release mode in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net

In my C# code I would like to wrap `Debug.WriteLine()` and `Console.WriteLine()` into one function, so that it targets the debug window in debug mode and console in release mode. What is the best way to achieve it? I am new to C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [System.Diagnostics.Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36hhw2t6.aspx) class.

Trace includes a WriteLine() method similar to that on the Debug and Console classes, and supports attaching/detaching various listeners at runtime or via config file, such as the [ConsoleTraceLister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener.aspx), [DefaultTraceListner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx) (for Debug), the [TextWriterTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) (for files), the [EventLogTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener.aspx), or you can create your for writing to places like database tables or syslogd aggregators.

You can just about change every current call to Debug or Console to use Trace instead, and just set the listeners you want to use. Note that the Trace methods are missing a few formatting features, but I think the configurable output source more than makes up for it.

Answer (score 4):

Always use Debug.WriteLine and add these lines to the beginning of your program:

```
#if !DEBUG
            var listeners = new TraceListener[] { new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out) };
            Debug.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joel's answer, another very simple solution would be this:

```
private void writeLine(String s)
{

    #if DEBUG
        Debug.WriteLine(s);
    #else
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    #endif
}
```

This uses preprocessor directives so that it will not write to console except in Release mode. Note, it's slightly redundant as all `Debug` calls are removed during a Release build anyway, even without the preprocessor directive.

Comment: You could also use the preprocessor directives to alter which Trace Listeners are attached.

Comment: what if I want to get all the overloads of Writeline() from both? Is there a way?